# How to control NIC traffic against process on RHEL6 or Fedora15?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

Now i have some processes, e.g 2. named P1, P2.
P1 and P2 will need to transmit data from NIC. Maybe we can take P1,P2 as two browser.

I have two questions:
1) I want to limit P1 max to 100KB/s, and P2 max to 200KB/s. How can I do for this?
2) I want to P1 use half of the NIC bandwidth, same to P2. They completely fair splitting bandwidth.  How can I do for this? cgroup or tc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right, cgroup + tc is the answer. You have a good example here : http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/06/manage-your-performance-with-cgroups-and-projects.html (look for "Networks, Too").

Comment: I'm sorry to reply you so later. the example in your links can help me to solve the question 1. But can't solve question2. cgroup maybe can't fairly splitting bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question #2 may be the new net_prio subsystem. It lets you set network priorities per interface. See:

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html-single/Resource_Management_Guide/index.html#net_prio